# How to using placement new while there is a overloaded operator new exist?

Tags: c++, overloading

we have this in our header:

```
#define new new(size_t, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

so when I use placement new

```
void* buffer = new char[512];
MyClass* t = new(buffer) MyClass;
```

an error came out:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'buffer'
```

So how to use overloaded new and placement new together?

I'm sorry I should to make it more clear.I cannot change the #define definition in some reason, so how to use placement new in this circumstance?

Comment: Don't `#define` keywords.  Period.

Comment: You cannot. Your program has undefined behaviour if you define macros with the names of keywords.

Comment: Note that this macro hack is brittle anyway. If you use, say, `std::vector`, it either won't be effective, or it will break outright.

Comment: Find the guy who wrote this header, give him a long long look in the face and remember how he looks, so that you won't hire him again by mistake.

Comment: That macros is so broken. You may not want too or think its hard too. But in the long run you have to remove that macro. It's existence is going to cause so many kludges (each kludge costing time and brittleness of the code) that it would be better to pay the cost of taking it out now. PS. that is **not** `overloaded operator new`.